# Target SELECT option JQuery

Tags: jquery, select, html-select

I am trying to target an `option` within a `select` dropdown through JQuery.

The HTML:

```
<select id="category-select" name="category">
    <option class="all" value="all">All</option>
    <option class="env-tech" value="environmental-technologies">Environmental Technologies</option>
    <option class="digital-media" value="digital-media">Digital Media</option>
    <option class="serv-consumer" value="services-consumer">Services/Consumer</option>
    <option class="bio" value="bio-technology">Medical/Biotechnolgy</option>
</select>
```

The JQuery

```
('#category-select option[value="environmental-technologies"]').click(function() {

    $('.portfolio-area').show().filter(':not(.environmental-technologies)').fadeOut(200);

 });
```

How do I achieve this? I have had no succes with other solutions on the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try doing

```
$(document).on("change","#category-select", function(){
    if($(this).val()=='environmental-technologies')
    {
        alert(1); // Your code $('.portfolio-area').show()....
    }
});
```